# How to use the meta viewport tag in nextjs 14 app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

I am trying to add the responisve viewport html meta tag to my root layout file (layout.tsx).

I am using Nextjs v14, with the app/ router.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'STB Radius',
  description: 'The STB Radius Manager',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

However, I am getting this warning in the terminal:

```
Warning: You're using `next/head` inside the `app` directory, please migrate to the Metadata API. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-3-migrating-nexthead for more details.
```

How to use the meta viewport tag in nextjs 14 app router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before 14 it was part of metadata but now it has its own API. Just like the Metadata, add:

```
export const viewport: Viewport = {
    initialScale: 1,
    width: 'device-width'
}
```

Link to documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-viewport

Comment: Can you add the reference from the documentation?

Comment: Added the link in the answer.